# Converting Teradata timestamp to PDT

Tags: teradata

for converting the timestamp to PST we use a query like

```
select start_ts AT 'America Pacific' from table_name;
```

How to specify the time zone for PDT. I was not able to find it in teradata docs

Comment: https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/aWY6mGNJ5CYJlSDrvgDQag - Does this section of the manual help explain DST and the AT TIMEZONE expression?

Comment: `'America Pacific'` follows the rules for daylight saving, i.e. either UTC-8 or or UTC-7.  Maybe you want `start_ts AT 'GMT-7'` or shorter `start_ts AT -7`?